# Can you remove things from the suggestions?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2017, intellisense

In Visual Studio, as you type it will try to suggest methods/properties for what you type.  I never use `Message` it's always `MessageBox`.  However, it never seems to learn that and always sits me on `Message` when I start to type.  Is there any way I can tell VS to stop suggesting `Message` so it will always land me on `MessageBox` instead?

Comment: Hi Ken, do you want use the MessageBox.Show or others. To use MessageBox.Show, we can use the code snippet "mbox" per this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/visual-csharp-code-snippets?view=vs-2019, it seems we cannot directly remove the 'Message' from the List Members since it also meet your type content.

Answer (score 0):

You can turn Quick Info off for C++ code by navigating to **Tools > Options > Text Editor > C/C++ > Advanced**, and setting `Auto Quick Info` to `false`.